# C++ Calling template method in a non-template class from the class itself

Tags: c++, templates

```
class Node {
public:
  template<class T>  T*   GetComponent() {
     return new T(this);  // actual code is more complicated!
  }

  Transform*   Transform() {
      return this->GetComponent<Transform>();   // invalid template argument for 'T', type expected
  }
};
```

But calling same method works from another place! like main().
What is wrong with this code!!!

Comment: maybe try to change the name of the `Transform` function so it is not the same as the name of the `Transform` class?

Comment: Well, patently `Transform` has never been defined...

Comment: This is only a part of the code. PLEASE .....

Comment: What is `Transform` supposed to be. A function or a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided has typos, as already have been mention. After fixing them you'll get the error you mentioned.

The reason why you get it is that you have a member function with a name `Transform`, same as the type you want to concretise `GetComponent` for. So, the solution is to "help" complier by using full type name, including namespace. This assumes that `Transform` is defined in a global namespace:

```
Transform*   Transform() {
    return this->GetComponent<::Transform>();
}
```

Use this if you have defined it in a namespace:

```
Transform*   Transform() {
    return this->GetComponent<::YOUR_NAMESPACE::Transform>();
}
```

EDIT: the full code I used:

```
class Node;
class Transform
{
public:
    Transform(Node*);
};

class Node {
public:
    template <class T>  
    T*   GetComponent() {
        return new T(this);
    }

    Transform*   Transform() {
        return this->GetComponent<::Transform>();
    }
};
```